# Weird behavior: Lambda inside list comprehension

Tags: python, lambda, list-comprehension

In python 2.6:

```
[x() for x in [lambda: m for m in [1,2,3]]]
```

results in:

```
[3, 3, 3]
```

I would expect the output to be [1, 2, 3]. I get the exact same problem even with a non list comprehension approach. And even after I copy m into a different variable.

What am I missing?

Comment: ... but this works with iterators.>>> l = (lambda: m for m in [1,2,3])
>>> [x() for x in l]

Comment: That's because a Generator does not create its values all at once, it creates them when they are requested.  A list comprehension and a generator expression are not the same, though they can often be used interchangeably.  There are situations (like this one) where the behavior is _significantly_ different.

Comment: why `x()` not just `x` ?? how is it different??

Comment: @amyassin - because x in this instance is a lambda (anonymous function declared on the fly).  He's calling `x()` to invoke it.  Really though, you should ask your own question.

Comment: @g.d.d.c thanx, i needed to know where to steer in searching...

Answer (score 20, accepted):

To make the lambdas remember the value of `m`, you could use an argument with a default value:

```
[x() for x in [lambda m=m: m for m in [1,2,3]]]
# [1, 2, 3]
```

This works because default values are set once, at definition time. Each lambda now uses its own default value of `m` instead of looking for `m`'s value in an outer scope at lambda execution time.

Comment: Awesome!  Didn't think of setting a default value to the lambda.  Great post.

Answer (score 8):

The effect you’re encountering is called [closures](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0227/), when you define a function that references non-local variables, the function retains a reference to the variable, rather than getting its own copy.  To illustrate, I’ll expand your code into an equivalent version without comprehensions or lambdas.

```
inner_list = []
for m in [1, 2, 3]:
    def Lambda():
         return m
    inner_list.append(Lambda)
```

So, at this point, `inner_list` has three functions in it, and each function, when called, will return the value of `m`.  But the salient point is that they all see the very same `m`, even though `m` is changing, they never look at it until called much later.

```
outer_list = []
for x in inner_list:
    outer_list.append(x())
```

In particular, since the inner list is constructed completely before the outer list starts getting built, `m` has already reached its last value of 3, and all three functions see that same value.

Answer (score 5):

Long story short, you don't want to do this.  More specifically, what you're encountering is an order of operations problem.  You're creating three separate `lambda`'s that all return `m`, but none of them are called immediately.  Then, when you get to the outer list comprehension and they're all called the residual value of `m` is 3, the last value of the inner list comprehension.

-- For comments --

```
>>> [lambda: m for m in range(3)]
[<function <lambda> at 0x021EA230>, <function <lambda> at 0x021EA1F0>, <function <lambda> at 0x021EA270>]
```

Those are three separate lambdas.

And, as further evidence:

```
>>> [id(m) for m in [lambda: m for m in range(3)]]
[35563248, 35563184, 35563312]
```

Again, three separate IDs.

Comment: Check the id() of the lambda. They are all the same.

Comment: So this means the lambda is holding a reference to m instead of the value of m. Is it possible to make the lambda hold the value of a variable ? Thanks!

Comment: @GeneralBecos - Not that I am aware of, no, though if someone else does know of a way and could add it as an additional comment I'd be happy to make note of it.  Unless it hurts your end result your approach with a generator is reasonable, and this would produce the expected output:  `[x() for x in (lambda: m for m in [1,2,3])]`

Answer (score 3):

Look at the `__closure__` of the functions. All 3 point to the same cell object, which keeps a reference to m from the outer scope:

```
>>> print(*[x.__closure__[0] for x in [lambda: m for m in [1,2,3]]], sep='\n')
<cell at 0x00D17610: int object at 0x1E2139A8>
<cell at 0x00D17610: int object at 0x1E2139A8>
<cell at 0x00D17610: int object at 0x1E2139A8>
```

If you don't want your functions to take m as a keyword argument, as per unubtu's answer, you could instead use an additional lambda to evaluate m at each iteration:

```
>>> [x() for x in [(lambda x: lambda: x)(m) for m in [1,2,3]]]
[1, 2, 3]
```

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I find this a more elegant solution. Lambda returns a function, so if we want to use the function, then we should use it. It's confusing to use the same symbol for the 'anonymous' variable in the lambda and for the generator, so in my example I use a different symbol to make it hopefully more clear.

```
>>> [ (lambda a:a)(i) for i in range(3)]
[0, 1, 2]
>>>
```

it's faster too.

```
>>> timeit.timeit('[(lambda a:a)(i) for i in range(10000)]',number=10000)
9.231263160705566
>>> timeit.timeit('[lambda a=i:a  for i in range(10000)]',number=10000)
11.117988109588623
>>>
```

but not as fast as map:

```
>>> timeit.timeit('map(lambda a:a,  range(10000))',number=10000)
5.746963977813721
```

(I ran these tests more than once, result was the same, this was done in python 2.7, results are different in python 3: the two list comprehensions are much closer in performance and both a lot slower, map remains much faster. )

Answer (score 0):

@unubtu's answer is correct. I recreated the scenario in Groovy with closures. Perhaps is illustrates what is going on.

This is analogous to `[x() for x in [lambda: m for m in [1,2,3]]]`

```
arr = []
x = 0
while (x < 3) {
  x++
  arr.add({ -> x })
}
arr.collect { f -> f() } == [3, 3, 3]
```

This is analogous to `[x() for x in [lambda m=m: m for m in [1,2,3]]]`

```
arr = []
x = 0
while (x < 3) {
  x++
  arr.add({_x -> { -> _x }}(x))
}
arr.collect { f -> f() } == [1, 2, 3]
```

Note that this would not happen if i used `[1,2,3].each {x -> ... }` instead of a while loop. Groovy while loops and Python list comprehensions both share its closure between iterations.

Answer (score -1):

I noticed that too. I concluded that lambda are created only once. So in fact your inner list comprehension will give 3 indentical functions all related to the last value of m.

Try it and check the id() of the elements.

[Note: this answer is not correct; see the comments]

Comment: The lambda is not created once.  `[lambda: m for m in [1,2,3]]` will produce three separate lambdas.

Comment: Yeah, noticed that. Sorry :) The start and the end of the id looked the same for me...