# Strange behavior with nested list comprehension

Tags: python, list-comprehension

I have the following piece of code:

```
[e for e in [sl] for sl in [1,[2,3],4,5]]
```

which I thought being equivalent (in terms of output) to:

```
[sl for sl in [1,[2,3],4,5]]
```

Yet, while the latter produces: `[1,[2,3],4,5]` the former returns: `[5, 5, 5, 5]`

---

I think it must have something do with how nested `for-statements` are evaluated.

I found a similar case here [Weird behavior: Lambda inside list comprehension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7368522/weird-behavior-lambda-inside-list-comprehension) but since it uses an anonymous functions, the reason behind this behavior should be different.

Clearly, there's something I'm missing and I don't see.

Thank you for any clarification

**UPDATE**

As Patrick pointed out, the order of the two `for` is wrong and shouldn't run unless `sl` was defined before. I fooled myself here because I ran the examples in the interpreter and `[sl for sl in [1,[2,3],4,5]]` was executed first leaving `sl` set to the last value of the list in `globals()`

Now it would be great to understand how this is evaluated

```
[e for e in [sl] for sl in [1,[2,3],4,5]]
```

in order to produce `[5, 5, 5, 5]` in output.

Comment: Even with the `for`s in the correct order, it won't run without a prior definition of `s1`.

Comment: Voted to close as a typo on that basis, and taking into consideration the accepted answer. This question cannot properly help others.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is `sl` defined elsewhere in your code?  Perhaps as `5`?  As written, your first example should not run, and does not run for me in Python 3.6. The correct way to write it would be

```
[e for sl in [1,[2,3],4,5] for e in [sl]]
```

Note that here `sl` is defined before it is used.

Edit:

Python reads list comprehensions left to right.  When it gets to `for e in [sl]`, it evaluates the expression `[sl]` based on what it already knows, without reading the rest of the line.  You list comprehension is then something like

```
[e for e in [5] for sl in [1,[2,3],4,5]]
```

As there are four `sl` in `[[1,[2,3],4,5]]`, you get `5` four times in the resultant list.

When writing list comprehensions, it's natural to write them from smallest to  biggest

```
e for e in x for x in y for y in z #wrong
```

but you should actually write them from right to left, so that the interpreter recognizes the identifiers that you use in the nested comprehensions

```
e for y in z for x in y for e in x
```

This is no different from regular `for` loops:

```
for e in x:
    for x in y:
        for y in z:
            print(e)
```

is pretty obviously wrong, and list comprehensions are no different.

Comment: Well no, it's just that line actually and I'm running the examples in the interpreter. But yes, you are right actually! I must have ran `[sl for sl in [1,[2,3],4,5]] ` before and so the `sl` remained set to the last value of the list in  `globals()`.  That explains also why the inverted `for` worked.  However, with `sl` set to `5` in globals, how would you explain the behavior of `[e for e in [sl] for sl in [1,[2,3],4,5]]`?

Comment: I mean, I understand that the leftmost `for` local `sl` would correctly override the global variable. I just want to understand how my solution is evaluated when `sl` is already set

Comment: @holak please see my edit (it got to big to fit in a comment).  If that still doesn't help, feel free to ask more.

Comment: @holak list comprehension variables "leaking" out of scope is a [known pseudo-bug in Python 2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4199355/6779307) that is no longer present in Python 3. If there's no organizational pressure on you to be using Python 2, you should consider switching.

Comment: list comprehension leaking the loop control variable is a nice catch - it caused the misunderstanding in the first place. No there's no org pressure, just playing around. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The only way that the code can run is if `sl` is defined elsewhere. If it is (as `5`), then the code:

```
sl = 5

[e for e in [sl] for sl in [1,[2,3],4,5]]
```

produces the output of:

```
[5,5,5,5]
```

**why?**

The reason this is happening is that the `for-loops` `evaluate` from the `left` to the `right`. So the first thing is that happens is `e` is assigned to `5` - just as you could right:

```
[i for i in [9]]
```

which would give `9`.

So now we know that regardless of the rightmost `for-loop`, the value of `e` will always be that of `sl` so in our case `5`. Now, why is the output `[5,5,5,5]`? Well its confusing because the variable `sl` is being re-used. However, this does not effect the `left` of the `list-comprehension` as it evaluates `left` to `right`. So `e` will always have the value from `[sl]` (`5`) no matter what `sl` is on the right hand side. The right hand `loop` simply acts as a counter. Since there are `4` elements in it (`1`, `[2,3]`, `4`, `5`), the left hand part is run `4` times. But `e` is always `5` so each of the times `e` is called, it is `5` - producing the result `[5,5,5,5]`.

To demonstrate that the right hand side is simply a counter, the following will **all** produce the same result of `[5,5,5,5]`:

```
[e for e in [sl] for _  in [1, [2,3], 4, 5]]
[e for e in [sl] for sl in [0, 0, 0, 0]]
[e for e in [sl] for _  in range(4)]
[e for e in [sl] for sl in range(4)]
```